# Im trying to get values of the following JSON object and display them in html using angularness

Tags: html, angularjs, json

In the following JSON object, I'm trying to get the value of the streets

Get business profile data :

```
{
        "_id": "56dd1bd4d0561b403f683bfd",
        "UserId": "56b301516b9064189049acb5",
        "WebURL": "2",
        "PhoneNumber": "3",
        "ContactEmail": "1@gmail.com",
        "AdditionalInfo": "",
        "__v": 0,
        "DateCreated": "2016-03-07T06:12:36.957Z",
        "Categories": [],
        "Addresses": [{
            "Street": "1",
            "City": "1",
            "State": "1",
            "Country": "1",
            "SuiteNumber": "1",
            "_id": "56dd1bd4d0561b403f683bfe"
        }]
    }
```

So far this is what I have:

```
    Info.GetData()
    .success(function (response){
        $scope.Data = response;
    })
    .error(function (response, status) {
        alert("Can Not Retrieve Company Info, Please Contact Admin")
    })

<div ng-repeat="x in Data.Addresses">
    {{x.Street}}
</div>
```

> I still can't get it working.

Comment: Have you error in console? Print in console your `response`.

Comment: In case you have duplicates in that array, you need to use [track by](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: Try changing $scope.Data = response; to $scope.Data = response.data;

Comment: @Lex , 'success' doesn't get the response object as the first argument, it gets the response object's 'data' property, so the OP's usage is correct. Having said that, the 'success' and 'error' methods are deprecated so it's better to use the 'then' method in which case, yes you would change to response.data :)

Comment: @o4ohel Oops, my bad. It didn't even click that he was using .success(). Sorry about that.

Comment: @Lex no worries :) I was a click away from giving the same advice, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Info.GetData()` is making a `$http` call and you are using success instead of then, you will still have to use then wherever there is a promise. If you are doing this

```
return 
angular.module('app').factory('Info', function($http) {
    return {
        getData: function() {
            return $http.get('url');
       };
    };
});
```

in your Info.getData(). You could instead do

```
return 
angular.module('app').factory('Info', function($http) {
    return {
        getData: function() {
            return $http.get('url').then(function(response)
               {
                    return response.data;
               }
        };
    };
});`
```

Also, you need to check if your service is returning a promise. If its a promise you should resolve it. You can't assume that your promise has a .success().